# What does SYNOPSIS part in perror man page mean?

Tags: c, errno

SYNOPSIS section in `perror`'s [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) is:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   void perror(const char *s);

   #include <errno.h>

   const char * const sys_errlist[];
   int sys_nerr;
   int errno;       /* Not really declared this way; see errno(3) */
```

according to [man page specification](https://linux.die.net/man/7/man-pages), SYNOPSIS section indicates that

> For functions, it shows any required data declarations or #include directives, followed by the function declaration.

The following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *ls_args[2] = {"nonsense", NULL};
    execv(ls_args[0], ls_args); // no return
    perror("execve failed");
    return 2;
}
```

outputs error message `execve failed: No such file or directory`, with corresponding `errno` being `2`

since `errno` is a global variable (actually a macro) defined in `errno.h`, and `errno.h` header is not included, how does this code trigger `errno` modification?

What does `#include <errno.h> ... int errno;` mean in the SYNOPSIS section? seems like `perror()` can be called without this portion of code, thanks!

Comment: The synopsis tells you that including stdio.h will give you the declaration of `perror`, and that including errno.h will give you declarations of `sys_nerr` and `errno`.  The sample code does not reference either of the two from errno.h.

Comment: Hi @WilliamPursell I wonder why the `#include<errno.h> ...` part is included in `perror()`'s synopsis if calling `perror()` doesn't require it at all, thanks!

Comment: It's telling you that you need it if you want to directly reference `sys_nerr` or `errno`

Comment: could you explain the mechanism of `errno` changing behind the scene, given that it's not included in the first place

Comment: Headers provide declarations for the compiler, but they have nothing to do with linkage.

Comment: `errno` is defined by the ISO C standard to be a modifiable lvalue of type `int`, and must not be explicitly declared; `errno` may be a macro. `errno` is `thread-local`; setting it in one  thread  does  not  affect  its value in any other thread. (from `man 3 errno`)

Comment: *"how does this code trigger `errno` modification?"* The value of `errno` can be written/read by any function executed by the thread. Which means that `execv` can, and does, change it when something goes wrong. BTW, the `no return` comment is only true when `execv` succeeds. When `execv` fails, it *does* return, after writing an error code to `errno`.

Comment: @user3386109 but `execv` is declared in `unistd.h`, which has no overlap with `errno.h`, how can it access & modify `errno`? I've also read that `errno` is modifiable by library functions, just curious about how it's implemented.

Comment: The library code that implements `execv()` or `perror()` in effect contains `#include <errno.h>` so it can use `errno`.  Just the same as in your code.

Comment: Hi @JonathanLeffler I also thought about that, but I can't find c files in glibc https://github.com/bminor/glibc, could you have a look and locate them? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the `include` folder only have header files

Comment: See: [`perror()`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/perror.c) and [`execv()`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/posix/execv.c).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sweet, thanks!

Comment: And yes, the `include` directory should only contain headers (and sub-directories containing more headers and sub-directories).  That's the way it is supposed to be.  Your compiler links your code with a pre-compiled library (`glibc`, for example) which contains the object code for all the functions you can call from the system library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C standard, the macro `errno` is declared in `errno.h` and you must include `errno.h` explicitly if you want to write a portable program which uses `errno`. The manpage synopsis is telling you that. (It is not saying that you need to include `errno.h` in order to use `perror`. Sometimes the Synopsis section tells you about other related library facilities.)

Nothing in the standard specifies what the definition of the `errno` macro is, or exactly where in the implementation you can find any objects referenced by the expansion of that definition. The implementation of `perror` obviously needs to be able to access whatever object `errno` refers to, but since it doesn't need to be portable, it is completely unspecified how that works.

In particular, recent C standards require that the object `errno` refers to be *thread-local*, so that every thread has its own `errno` object. (If this were not the case, the mechanism would be essentially unusable in multithreaded code.) The precise implementation of thread-local storage is also not specified by the standard, and on a particular implementation it might be mapped onto some facility provided by the underlying operating system.